# Previous page instance not maintained after navigation in prism

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using the latest version of Prism.MVVM in Xamarin.Forms. In this, if I try to navigate to second page from the first page, the first page is initialized once again. i.e., the constructor of the first page is called once again.

For example, I am having Page1.xaml and Page2.xaml pages with their respective view models(those will be created and registered automatically while creating in prism).
I navigating to Page2 from Page1 like below,
**NavigationAsync("Navigation/Page1/Page2")**

While navigating, Page1.xaml's constructor is called so that the page is created newly which lead I could not able to maintain the Page1.xaml instance. Also, please note that Page1.xaml is a Master-Details page.

Is this a behavior in Prism? If so how can I overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample that demonstrates the issue you’re facing

Answer (score 0):

Navigating away from a XAML page destroys it in UWP. You can preserve a page’s state data (and avoid re-construction) by adding a single line in a XAML page’s  tag:

```
NavigationCacheMode="Required"
```

Does it work the same in Xamarin?